# Async Receive, Multiple Xml-Data Receiving, sometime causing multiple root elements error

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
if (bytesRead > 0)
{                    
    if (recievedData.Trim().EndsWith("</CRootSystem>", stringComparison.Ordinal))
    {
        if (state.packetCount > 0)
        {
            state.sb.Append(recievedData);
            state.totalSize += bytesRead;
            state.packetCount++;

            totalSize = state.totalSize;

            #region Insert into Packet
                Packet packet = new Packet(state.totalSize, state.packetCount);
                packetManager.Packets.Add(packet);
            #endregion

            parseXmlFeed(state.sb.ToString());

            #region Reset
                state.clear();
                recievedData = null;
            #endregion
        }
        else            
        {
            totalSize = bytesRead;

            #region Insert into Packet
                Packet packet = new Packet(state.totalSize, state.packetCount);
                packetManager.Packets.Add(packet);
            #endregion

            parseXmlFeed(recievedData);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        state.sb.Append(recievedData);
        state.totalSize += bytesRead;
        state.packetCount++;
    }
}
else //This part of code will never reached, because the connection and comm. with the server is never closed
{
    Display.Write("Nomore data Recieved.");
    receiveDone.Set();
}
```

This code actually works great. But sometimes I am getting error where I parse XML **parseXmlFeed(s);**

I am getting the following error:

*There are multiple root elements. Line X, position Y.*

I know what this error means. I have more then one Root element in my xml-data.

But Server **never** sends wrong xml. Server sends long data (which is 8192byte each)

Example: [8192 Byte] + [8192 Byte] + [176 Byte]

But theoretically, I should never have a xml-data with 2 roots.

I am really stuck at this point.

I think I have error where I append the datas or should use lock, mutex, semiphore or monitor?

Should I lock data before appending?

or the question is, How to handles Long datas correctly?

*Btw. I am using BeginReceive/EndReceive.*

Changed the above code to:

```
    if (bytesRead > 0)
    {
        state.sb.Append(recievedData);
        state.totalSize += bytesRead;
        state.packetCount++;

        string data = state.sb.ToString();
        int dataSize = state.totalSize;

        if (data.TrimEnd().EndsWith("</CRootSystem>", StringComparison.Ordinal))
        {
            #region Insert into Packet
                Packet packet = new Packet(state.totalSize, state.packetCount);
                packetManager.Packets.Add(packet);
            #endregion

            parseXmlFeed(data);

            #region Reset
                state.clear();
                recievedData = null;
            #endregion
        }
        else
        {
            Display.Write("Waiting...");
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        Display.Write("No more data Recieved.");
        receiveDone.Set();
    }
```

Comment: Do you have some form of synchronization between your client and your server? Specifically, does your server wait for acknowledgement from your client before sending the next `<CRootSystem>` document? If not, isn’t it possible that you might be receiving two documents within the same packet?

Comment: Server is from another provider and sends always 8192Byte as buffer_size. server sending continuously, you have to check if its long xml or single xml

Comment: Yes, but does it only send one `<CRootSystem>` document and then stop? Or may it send another one later on the same connection?

Comment: Server sends nonstop. You have to check for EndRootTag or Validate Xml to check if it is really a single xmldata <= 8192 or long xmldata which is > 8192

Answer (score 1):

From your explanation, my guess is that you’re getting the error when you receive multiple `<CRootSystem>` elements within a single read. The 8192-byte buffer size is not set by the server, but by the [`ReceiveBufferSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.receivebuffersize.aspx) property of your `TcpClient` (whose default value happens to be 8192 bytes). Thus, if the server sends multiple batches of data in close succession, you might receive them within a single `BeginReceive` callback.

Another issue: What if the total size of a single `<CRootSystem>` document happens to be, say, 8195 bytes? In that case, the first read would give you `<CRootSystem>…(data)…</CRootSyst`, whilst the second read would give you `em>`. The `EndsWith("</CRootSystem>")` condition is never satisfied, since the close tag is never contained within `recievedData` in entirety.

Your code will require some significant reworking. To start off, for correctness (but not efficiency), you could replace:

```
if (recievedData.Trim().EndsWith("</CRootSystem>", stringComparison.Ordinal))
```

with:

```
state.sb.Append(receivedData);
int endTagIndex = state.sb.ToString().IndexOf("</CRootSystem>", StringComparison.Ordinal);
if (endTagIndex != -1)
```

…and then extract your XML from the first `endTagIndex + "</CRootSystem>".Length` characters of your string.

**Edit**: Here’s a quick-and-dirty fix to stop your error. Replace:

```
parseXmlFeed(data);
```

with:

```
Regex rootRegex = new Regex(@"<CRootSystem.*?</CRootSystem>", RegexOptions.Singleline);
foreach (Match match in rootRegex.Matches(data))
    parseXmlFeed(match.Value);
```

Comment: But server "never" sends multiple <CRootSystem> elements and sends as 8192 data blocks. But u just made me think better now, with the 8195 example! thank you.

Comment: But using IndexOf is not a good idea, cuz u have to search in 8192 Bytes to find </CRootSystem>

Comment: I assumed the server might send blocks of smaller size? If the string representation of a `<CRootSystem>` element takes only 1000 bytes, wouldn’t the server send it as a 1000-byte block? In that case, the server might send several ‘small’ elements – separately, but consecutively – which get received as a single 8192-byte block on your client.

Comment: You might potentially have to search in significantly more than 8192 bytes, depending on the total size of your `<CRootSystem>` document. One optimization would be to retain the last `"</CRootSystem>".Length - 1` characters from your previous `receivedData`, and prepend it to the current one before comparing.

Comment: Check the question please, I have changed the code but I still get the same error, "more then one root elements"